# How to achieve the following? C++ "advanced" map/list/array?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create some sort of list, map or what ever may be suggested that does the following

```
something [] = { 
        mainvalue1 = 2001 { 
            value2 = 1905
            value3 = 2000
            result = 500

            value2 = 1910
            value3 = 2030
            result = 700
        } 
        mainvalue2 = 2005 { 
            value2 = 1635
            value3 = 2070
            result = 300

            value2 = 2310
            value3 = 5930
            result = 599
        } 
}
```

cout << "result: " << something[2001][1905][2000] << endl;

> > result: 500

cout << "result: " something[2001][1910][2030] << endl;

> > result: 700

cout << "result: " something[2005][2310][5930] << endl;

> > result: 599

**Is this possible? I would appreciate if someone could guide me how to start my thought process or give me an example how this can be achievable in C++**

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you elaborate on your use-case ?

Comment: Can you please give use a better description of your use cases?

Comment: `map<int, map<pair<int, int>, int>>` would do the trick.

Comment: Thanks eljay! your example was used as answers so I cant upvote this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your structure utterly confusing, but it's possible to make the lookup *nearly* like you want it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::map<std::vector<int>, int>> something{
        {2001, {
            {{1905, 2000}, 500},
            {{1910, 2030}, 700}
        }},
        {2005, {
            {{1635, 2070}, 300},
            {{2310, 5930}, 599}
        }}
    };

    std::cout << "result: " << something[2001][{1905,2000}] << '\n';
    //>> result: 500

    std::cout << "result: " << something[2001][{1910,2030}] << '\n';
    //>> result: 700

    std::cout << "result: " << something[2005][{2310,5930}] << '\n';
    //>> result: 599
}
```

If there are always *two* values (`value2` and `value3`) in the above `std::vector<int>`, you can replace it with a `std::pair<int, int>` instead:

```cpp
std::map<int, std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int>> something[...};
```

Note: A `std::map` is *ordered* (with respect to the *keys* in the map). If you don't need it to be ordered you can replace the outer `std::map` with a `std::unordered_map`. The lookup and insertion etc. is usually a bit quicker that way.

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
//...
std::unordered_map<int, std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int>> something{...};
```

Comment: @Phoenix You are welcome. I used a `std::vector<int>` for `value2, value3`. If that's a fixed number of values (always two) you may use something cheaper, like a `std::pair<int,int>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<int, map<int, map<int, int>>> something;
    something[2001][1905][2000] = 500;
    something[2001][1910][2030] = 700;
    something[2005][2310][5930] = 599;
    
    cout << "result: " << something[2001][1905][2000] << endl;
    cout << "result: " << something[2001][1910][2030] << endl;
    cout << "result: " << something[2005][2310][5930] << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use data-only structs or `std::tuple` for that kind of thing:
Tuple example:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>> dataVectorName;
```

Struct example:

```
struct MyData
{
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;
 }
std::vector<MyData> dataVectorName;
```

I always use and recommend `std::tuple` for data array. In such cases it is faster but does not seem user friendly. And to solve that problem, you can fake variables with `typedef` or `using`. And it's easy for nested datas.

Comment: Better than other examples below. It may look complicated at first but you'll get used to it.

Comment: _"It's faster"_ - I think that may be true when there are this few values in the container.  It would be interesting to see a performance measurement that supports that statement as a general truth though.